# Fastest way to get the total number of records for a query

Tags: kendo-ui, progress-4gl, openedge

I'm currently developing a REST API in OpenEdge (using the new object-oriented WebSpeed handlers), to be consumed by a Kendo grid widget.

One area that I'm really struggling with is implementing paging - the Kendo grid requires the API to provide it with a total number of records in order to determine how many pages there are. [The only recommended way I've found of doing it](https://documentation.progress.com/output/oemobile1151/index.html#page/oemobile/updating-business-entities-for-new-mobile-apps-i.html#wwconnect_header) is to do a `PRESELECT` query and then use `NUM-RESULTS`, like so:

```
CREATE QUERY hQuery.
hQuery:SET-BUFFERS(BUFFER sales_order:HANDLE).
hQuery:QUERY-PREPARE("PRESELECT EACH sales_order WHERE co_no = 1").
hQuery:QUERY-OPEN().
oJson:Add("total", hQuery:NUM-RESULTS).
```

This, predictably, is stupidly slow - the requests to the server went up from 72ms to 500ms per page, making the grid feel very sluggish. This is on a very low page size, too!

The obvious solutions here are:

- **Cache the number of records:** I don't have the authority to make database changes, and it would require updates to a legacy system to keep this in sync, so I feel like this would open a can of worms.
- **Get the number of records asynchronously:** If you don't return the total in the original request, [the Kendo grid will only let you get it through a synchronous request](http://www.telerik.com/forums/setting-total-with-datasource-schema-to-make-paging-work-in-grid), which I can't imagine will work wonders for the user experience.

So, my question is, are there faster ways of getting the total number of records for a query?

Comment: This subject is also discussed in the Common Component Specification for the Business Entity which just went into the community review. The Count is a challenge. Caching is a great idea. Store the number of results in a DB table, populate that over night. When no cache is available, you must do it like you did in code. Surround it with a STOP-AFTER 1 block, so that it does not get worse than 1 second.

Comment: @MikeFechner: I'll have to make the argument for implementing the caching to my boss, then. Thanks for the info, I'll take a look at the CCS.

Comment: You should also consider to add some logic to your JavaScript code, that changes the text pattern for the Kendo UI grid pager: 1 - 10 of ??? should dynamically turn into 1 - 10 when the count is not accurate or cannot be determined at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is still a issue in OE.

**Caching was mentioned, but it will only work if no filter is applied, as the total number of records is dependent on the filter criteria.**

The only thing you can do to improve performance is including FIELDS option in the PRESELECT

```
hQuery:QUERY-PREPARE("PRESELECT EACH sales_order FIELDS(table_field_here) WHERE co_no = 1").
```

This is the best thing you can do so far, at least is what is recommended in this article: [4GL. WHICH IS THE FASTEST WAY TO COUNT RECORDS IN A TABLE?](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P5496)

Comment: My boss made the same suggestion, but we weren't certain if there was something we were missing, so thanks for the confirmation! Feels slightly inelegant having to do that on every query, but it brings the request time down to within a few milliseconds of the version without the count, so I'm not complaining!

Comment: I had the same struggle. FIELDS has never been an elegant solution, but in this specific scenario it's not that bad as you'll most likely never change it.